# Convex Hull as Mesh

Tags: python, physics

I would very much like to get the Convex Hull (of the Rigid Body Collision shape) as an actual mesh.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Edit mode(<kbd>Tab</kbd>) > Select All(<kbd>a</kbd>) > Mesh > Vertices (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>)> Convex Hull (<kbd>h</kbd>):

[image: Edit mode(<kbd>Tab</kbd>) > Select All(<kbd>a</kbd>) > Mesh > Vertices (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>)> Convex Hull (<kbd>h</kbd>)]

Answer (score 10):

**Convex hull bmesh operator**

> **[`bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input, use_existing_faces)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bmesh.ops.html#bmesh.ops.convex_hull)**
>
> **Convex Hull**
>
> Builds a convex hull from the vertices in ‘`input`’.
>
> If ‘`use_existing_faces`’ is true, the hull will not output triangles that are covered by a pre-existing face.
>
> All hull vertices, faces, and edges are added to ‘geom.out’. Any input elements that end up inside the hull (i.e. are not used by an
> output face) are added to the ‘`interior_geom`’ slot. The ‘`unused_geom`’
> slot will contain all interior geometry that is completely unused.
> Lastly, ‘`holes_geom`’ contains edges and faces that were in the input
> and are part of the hull.

Test script, creates a convex hull for the active mesh object.

**EDIT** Update for 2.8. Removes interior geometry of convex hull.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from mathutils import Vector, Matrix

context = bpy.context
scene = context.scene
ob = context.object
me = ob.data
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(me)
copy = ob.copy()

me = bpy.data.meshes.new("%s convexhull" % me.name)
ch = bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=bm.verts)
bmesh.ops.delete(
        bm,
        geom=ch["geom_unused"] + ch["geom_interior"],
        context='VERTS',
        )
bm.to_mesh(me)
copy.name = "%s (convex hull)" % ob.name
copy.data = me

scene.collection.objects.link(copy)
```

[image]
*Suzanne and convex hull Suzanne*

**Horror mesh.**

If the input is a horror mesh of overlapping faces it may be an idea to reduce the mesh to verts only before using the convex hull operator.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
from math import radians

# Create a cube
bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add(location=(0,0,0), size=2)
me = bpy.context.object.data

# Get a BMesh representation
bm = bmesh.new()   # create an empty BMesh
bm.from_mesh(me)   # fill it in from a Mesh

# Spin the cube 45deg around the y-axis in 2 steps
ret = bmesh.ops.spin(bm,
                     geom=bm.verts[:] + bm.edges[:],
                     angle=radians(45.0),
                     steps=2,
                     axis=(0.,1.,0.),
                     cent=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

# reduce to verts only.
bmesh.ops.delete(bm, geom=bm.edges, context='EDGES_FACES')

# Create the resulting convex hull of the spin operation
ch = bmesh.ops.convex_hull(bm, input=bm.verts)

# Remove everything but the convex hull
bmesh.ops.delete(
        bm,
        geom=ch["geom_unused"] + ch["geom_interior"],
        context='VERTS',
        )

# Export the bmesh back to the original mesh
bm.to_mesh(me)
bm.free()
```