# Any Python code examples of bmesh operations on multiple objects?

Tags: python

I'm trying to iterate through multiple selected objects and perform bmesh operations. Unfortunately, I get errors such as index 0 out of range when trying to perform basic tasks such as selecting vertex index 0 on the next object in the selection.

I can iterate through objects and perform bpy operations, and I can perform bmesh operations on single objects fine. Unfortunately I get stuck when I try to perform index specific bmesh operations when iterating through all selected objects.

Would anyone be able to give me a basic example that would iterate through selected objects and e. g delete vertex with an index of 0 using bmesh? I'm using Blender 2.8

Thanks.

Comment: Example of bmesh operation on multiple objects https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/128263/15543

Comment: Thanks, that gave a great example, just what I was after.

Answer (score 2):

This is an example based upon batFINGER's link that uses a vertex index.

```
import bpy
import bmesh

context = bpy.context
mesh_obs = [o for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH']
bm = bmesh.new()

for ob in mesh_obs:
    me = ob.data
    bm.from_mesh(me)

    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    bm.verts.remove(bm.verts[0])

    bm.to_mesh(me)
    me.update()
    bm.clear()
```